# Why does IParseable<T> need to be recursive?

Tags: c#, recursion, interface, c#-11.0, .net-generic-math

Why does `IParseable<T>` place the `T : IParseable<T>` constraint on `T`?  What is this recursive constraint needed for?
[image]

Comment: That is, if my T implements `IParseable<T>` then my T has to implement `IParseable<T>`

Comment: Please don't paste code as images. Always paste as text.

Answer (score 6):

This is so called [Curiously_recurring_template_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) (CRTP) and as far as I understand it is not strictly required (and actually it can't enforce the "correct" behaviour) but as mentioned in the [Preview Features in .NET 6 – Generic Math](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/) article it's usage is a hint to support one of the quite important scenarios for static abstract interface members calls - using it via generic interfaces:

> This general pattern is sometimes referred to as the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP) and is key to allowing the feature to work.

Let's imagine the following interface:

```cs
public interface IParseable1<TSelf>
    // where TSelf : IParseable1<TSelf>
{
    static abstract TSelf Parse(string s, IFormatProvider? provider);

    static abstract bool TryParse([NotNullWhen(true)] string? s, IFormatProvider? provider, out TSelf result);
}
```

and next method:

```cs
static T InvariantParse<T>(string s)
    where T : IParseable1<T>
{
    return T.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

If we implement next classes pair:

```cs
class MyClass1
{
}

class MyClass : IParseable1<MyClass1>
{
    public static MyClass1 Parse(string s, IFormatProvider? provider)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static bool TryParse([NotNullWhen(true)] string? s, IFormatProvider? provider, out MyClass1 result)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then next call will not compile:

```cs
var x = InvariantParse<MyClass>("");
```

And while CRTP does not prevent from "incorrect" usage (i.e. `class MyClass1 : IParsable<MyClass1>` will allow `class MyClass : IParsable<MyClass1>`, as far as I remember there is no language construct to enforce such behaviour) it is heavily hinting on the desired usage.

Note that `class MyClass : IParsable<MyClass1>` can be used in similar method but it becomes quite clumsy (partly due to specifics of C# generic types inference):

```cs
public static TOut InvariantParseTwoGenerics<T, TOut>(string s)
    where T : IParseable1<TTO>
{
    return T.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}

var x1 = InvariantParseTwoGenerics<MyClass, MyClass1>("");
```

[Post from Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2022/09/modern-csharp-techniques-1-curiously-recurring-generic-pattern.html) discussing CRTP.

**UPD**

There was a [breaking change](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-7-generic-math/#breaking-changes-since-net-6) between .NET 6 and .NET 7 - `System.IParseable` was renamed to `System.IParsable`

Comment: Yes, I agree. The `TSelf` is hinting heavily.