# How do I test if a type T implements IParsable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, static-methods

.NET 7 recently introduced `IParsable` as an interface, and I'd like to check for its presence. Some test that will return `true` if `T` implements `IParsable<T>` and `false` otherwise.

Say I want to return an object that is of type `T` when `T` has a `Parse` method, for example:

```cs
T ParseAs<T>(string s)
{
    if (typeof(IParsable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
        return T.Parse(s);
    }
    else
    {
        //do something else...
    }
}
```

I would hope this to check if `T` implements `IParsable<T>` and grant me access to the `Parse` and `TryParse` methods inside. I don't seem to be able to use `T` as a type argument for `IParsable`, instead receiving this exception:

> CS0314
> The type '`T`' cannot be used as type parameter '`TSelf`' in the generic type or method '`IParsable<TSelf>`'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from '`T`' to '`System.IParsable<T>`'

I also receive the above error if I try to use `is`:

```cs
s is IParsable<T>
```

How would I resolve this?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/503359/1974021

Comment: That compiles, but doesn't allow me to do T.Parse(s) - do you know why that is?

Comment: `IParsable` is [recursively defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73409612/11683), so you need to establish that `T` is `IParsable<T>` *before* you could say `is IParsable<T>`...

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly in saying that before I can check if T is IParsable<T>, I have to know that T is IParsable<T>? That sounds like a catch-22.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to use `T.Parse()` syntax - you need to know *at compile time* that `T` implements `IParseable<T>`. The only way you can be sure about that at compile time is to explicitly say that:

```
T ParseAs<T>(string s) where T: IParsable<T> {
    return T.Parse(s, null);
}
```

If you have just type `T` without explicitly saying it's `IParsable<T>` - it's not possible to use `T.Parse` syntax and you should use reflection all the way. That is first you check if `T` implements that interface via reflection, and then you again use reflection to call that static method:

```
T ParseAs<T>(string s) {
    var isParsable = typeof(T).GetInterfaces().Any(c => c.IsGenericType && c.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IParsable<>));
    if (isParsable) {
        var parse = typeof(T).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Parse" && c.GetParameters().Length == 2 && c.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(string) && c.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType == typeof(IFormatProvider));
        if (parse != null)
            return (T) parse.Invoke(null, new object[] { s, null });
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

That's of course pretty ugly and you'll likely won't want to do that.

Comment: The reflection approach was the one I was using prior to this update, and I was looking to replace it with something more elegant. Thank you for the answer - it exactly answers my question.